# SQL comparison of dates does not work

Tags: sql, date, asp-classic, comparison, getdate

This code does not work:

```
conn.Execute("CREATE PROCEDURE mySuperProcedure 
AS
BEGIN 
    IF GETDATE() >= DATEADD(hour," & waitHours & ",
        DATEADD(minutes," & waitMinutes & ",'" & now & "') 
    BEGIN
        blah blah...
    END
END")
```

A SQL Agent Job runs this procedure every few seconds. It shall not do the "blah blah..." part until a certain time, but it does it every time because the **IF** statement returns **true**.

What could possibly be wrong? It makes no sense at all... :'(

Comment: I think you forgot an extra closing bracket `DATEADD(hour," & waitHours & ",DATEADD(minutes," & waitMinutes & ",'" & now & "')` here.It should be `DATEADD(hour," & waitHours & ",
DATEADD(minutes," & waitMinutes & ",'" & now & "'))`

Comment: Change it to printing the sql instead of executing it and post that here.

Comment: Also `minutes` should be `minute`.

Comment: Well, I wrote this down quickly, it's not a copy and paste. The error turned out to be that the **now** code from ASP gave a different format of date, **mm/dd/yyyy**, while the SQL is operating in **dd/mm/yyyy**

Answer (score 1):

not clear what you try to achieve but a quick look shows 2 syntax errors:
ist **MINUTE** not minutes and you are missing a **closing parenthesis** in your dateadd

some questions that come to mind:

- do you try to create the stored procedure every time the job
  executes?
- why not set the job to execute a the time you want it
  to run instead of checking every second if that time has come by
  running the job? :)
- why the dynamic SQL?

Comment: Well, I wrote this down quickly, it's not a copy and paste. The error turned out to be that the **now** code from ASP gave a different format of date, **mm/dd/yyyy**, while the SQL is operating in **dd/mm/yyyy**

Comment: It's dynamic because the user is to select when a certain change in the DB shall happen.

Comment: I see - so could you not create the sql job after the user has selected the time he want's it to run?